# Xcode upgrade and ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

Tags: macos, xcode

how could I prune ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator before xcode upgrade of obsolete simulators that I never used?

They keep accumulating and at some point I run out of space unable to upgrade xcode.

Comment: Almost, This one implied "is there a cheapskate way to automate the process rather than do it manually" ;-)

Comment: well, there is this xcrun simctl delete unavailable answer which does the automation